# JavaScript: Get object reference of callback function

Tags: javascript, oop

My program contains a method that is passed a callback function. This callback function may be within another object. Here is a rough snipped (may not be proper JavaScript, just to get an idea):

```
var myobj = {
  f1: function(callback) {
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  hr.onload = callback.bind(this);
  },

  f2: function() {
    this.f1(this.f3);
  },

  f3: function(event) {
  }
}
```

In this case, writing `this` as parameter to `callback.bind` works. However, think of another object:

```
var theirobj = {
  f4: function() {
    myobj.f1(this.f3);
  },

  f5: function(event) {
  }
}
```

Now, it does not work anymore, because `this` refers to `myobj`, but `callback` refers to a functon in `theirobj`.

So, the `bind` used to assign the `onload` event handler of `XMLHttpRequest` needs the object variable of the callback function. Is there something like `callback.getInstanceVariable()` or `callback.instance` in the `Function` prototype? How can get this reference?

Comment: Bind when passing the callback to `f1`! `this.f1(this.f3.bind(this))` `f1` shouldn't need to and in fact *can't* worry about this.

Comment: @deceze Great and fast! If you turn your comment into answer, I'll accept it. Also, is this really a duplicate? I saw the other post before I posted my question, but I could not see how the question describes my problem.